# How do we call recursive function on react js in class based components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do we call a recursive function in react js using class based component. tried almost all the ways its not taking the inner function call.

please find the below code,

```
 hasValueDeep=(json, findValue)=> {
        const values = Object.values(json);
        let hasValue = values.includes(findValue);
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                hasValue = hasValue || this.hasValueDeep(value, findValue);
            }
        })
        return hasValue;
    }
```

the above code is a function which will call the same function inside. but while compiling the code getting the error hasValueDeep is undefined.

this.hasValueDeep(value, findValue) in inside the function is not calling the same function.

a help would be really appreciable.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Swap the function callback with arrow function, or use bind on that function inside the forEach. Or use simple for syntax that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this part of your code :

```
values.forEach((value)=> { // here
    if (typeof value === "object") {
        hasValue = hasValue || this.hasValueDeep(value, findValue);
    }
})
```